# Might be beneficial to include a page explaining what answers should be like when someone joins with better reward for reading the FAQ

Tags: discussion

I'm sure for those of you who have used dropbox you remember that you get extra space for taking a tour (I think if my memory is accurate) of dropbox. I've been seeing some complaints lately about how newbies aren't researching before hand and the such.

When I joined, I remember skipping the faq about questions (being a newbie). I believe if we reward reading the faq somehow, it might be beneficial. (However we may need to increase the points needed for certain things so that someone can't make an account and have a ton of benefits fast and spam)

Comment: We also have http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: (answering here so as not to spam Jorge with messages) I have to say, if I ever tried to use a site and it asked me to pass a _quiz_ in order to post, I would just laugh my head of and never visit again.

Comment: I'm not saying that it should be required. that, I agree would be quite annoying. What I’m saying is that if you take the quiz you get some (more enticing) benefit that is better than a badge.

Answer (score 6):

The tour does exactly this:

- https://askubuntu.com/tour

It even gives you a badge for completing it.

Comment: I didn't remember seeing that I get a badge for doing this, so to confirm I made a new account to see. I saw the faq page, but I did not see anything that made obvious that I get a badge or reputation for looking at it.

Comment: I now see that you get the badge, the problem is, I didn't actually read the page and I still got the badge. When I joined I didn't realize that I would get a badge for reading that page.

Comment: So it may be beneficial to somehow entice people (newbies like me) to read the entire page.

Comment: If someone is going to only read the page because we give them a badge and can't be bothered to read it otherwise, do you really want them posting?

Comment: @rajlego how exactly would you check that the user has read it anyway? An exam perhaps? Software that tracks eye movements? I don't see how anything _more_ than offering a Useless Internet Reward Badge® could be done.

Comment: @terdon While it may seem silly to institute a quiz, I believe it would pay off. It would improve the overall site as a whole, I believe. And I think maybe offering some rep (but as stated before you may want to increase the barriers to doing certain tasks as well)

Comment: @JorgeCastro Who would join in the first place? Few people would join askubuntu without actually having a question; they are also most likely newbies, looking for a quick fix to a problem. They (as I know from experience) will most likely not care at all about reading the faq very much. In order to reduce the amount of people who don't read the faq (which is probably quite high) it would be beneficial to institute some reward like rep (because not all people are willing to read faqs for the benefit of a community, and a badge is not the most enticing reward)